# PHP & Apache Mod rewrite: search?keyword

Tags: php, regex, apache, search, mod-rewrite

these are the rewrite rules I normally use for clean urls,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?pg_url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$  index.php?pg_url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

they will accept requested urls such as,

```
mysite/home
mysite/portfolio/photograhy
```

but how can I set the rewrite rule for seaching such as,

```
mysite/search?photograhy
mysite/search?painting
```

I tried with this one below,

```
RewriteRule ^search?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?pg_url=search&keyword=$1[L,QSA]
```

they keyword seach won't appear correctly, but I will get this below whatever I search for,

```
echo $_REQUEST['keyword'];


h[L,QSA] // result
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a RewriteCond for the Query String, a la:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keyword=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$
```

You'll need to adjust your query to do something like `?keyword=photography`

Here's some reading on the subject:  http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString